# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to net.minidev.json.JSONObject

Tags: java

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to net.minidev.json.JSONObject

```
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader(location.getAbsolutePath()));
    JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) obj;
```

Comment: it may be relate to your jar or dependency.I think your import should be like this import com.google.gson.Gson; after adding jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does your input file look like?

If it's content is something like:

```
"some string"
```

then the call to `jsonParser.parse()` will return `java.lang.String` causing the subsequent failure of the cast to `JSONObject`.

Comment: The content is a file from https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/indexes/1.7.4.json

Comment: I just tried the following code on the file you linked:     JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    Object obj = jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("1.7.4.json"));
    JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) obj;    
    System.out.println(((JSONObject) jobj.get("objects")).get("icons/icon_16x16.png"));  and I got the following output: {"size":3665,"hash":"bdf48ef6b5d0d23bbb02e17d04865216179f510a"}. are you sure you're still seeing that class-cast-exception?